# Help with Resolution Refutation Problem

Tags: discrete-mathematics, artificial-intelligence, conjunctive-normal-form

I'm trying to convert Solve a Resolution Refutation problem. The problem states: **Knowledge Base is  ∀ (, ). Prove using resolution-refutation that  ∀ (, ). Note: β = F(y, x)** This is what I think it might be:

Convert Clauses to CNF:

1   `∀xy F(x,y)` -From KB

2   `∀x F(x,A(x))`

3   `F(x,A(x))` -CNF

Convert negation β to CNF:

1   `¬∀x F(A(x),x)` -Negation of β

2   `∃x¬ F( A(x),x)`

3   `¬ F( A(x),x)` -CNF

Proof by Resolution-Refutation

1   `F(x,A(x))` -From KB

2   `¬F( A(x),x)` -Negation of β

3   `Contradiction` -Line 1 & 2
, respectively.
[Table Format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ryw67.png)

Is that right? (For some reason the KB being F(x, y) and the Conclusion trying to prove F( ***y***, x), it makes me think I'm missing something.) If not, could you explain to me what I'm missing? Thanks!